# Color printing from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, printing, document

I'm trying to print C# code from Visual Studio 2010 to a Konica BizHub Color Printer.  Only the line numbers are printing in color.  Does anyone know if there is some Visual Studio setting or plug-in to allow the text of the code to be printed in color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to do from VS2010 without 3rd party tools. They cut in from production due to time constraints.

There are some tools such as this that have a workaround though

http://www.starprinttools.com/

Or you could always copy and paste into Word or an e-mail or something

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

There is a free extension available now, that puts back in color printing. Not all 2008 'features' are supported, but you get color:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/00ec88c2-1553-47d2-8170-3c5baa0c6e44/